# For loop printing all steps, but i only need the last

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Im making a hangman game in python.
and now i got stuck in a problem.
i want the for loop to print display that says

wanted output: `['_', '_', '_', '_', '_']`

```
but it prints:
['_']
['_', '_']
['_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
```

I understand this is the for loop, but how do I make it only print what I want?
thank you for your time and help!

```py
import random
word_list = ["aardvark", "baboon", "camel"]
chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)
# Testing code
print(f'Pssst, the solution is {chosen_word}.')
display = []
for letter in chosen_word:
    display.append("_")
print(display)
guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you indented the `print(display)` statement and added it to the for loop. Just unindent the loop and The code should work.

```
import random
word_list = ["aardvark", "baboon", "camel"]
chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)
#Testing code
print(f'Pssst, the solution is {chosen_word}.')
display = []
for letter in chosen_word:
    display.append("_")
print(display)
guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
```

Output:

```
Pssst, the solution is aardvark.
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
Guess a letter:
```

Comment: wow thanks. You probably guessed it, but im pretty new to coding. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I implement this to practice. Sure that can be more elaborate but for a reference should work:

```
import random

WORD_LIST = ["aardvark", "baboon", "camel"]
MAX_POINTS = 5
chosen_word = random.choice(WORD_LIST)

word = ["".join("_") for i in chosen_word]
print(word)


def guessing():
    # Initial setup
    initial_points = MAX_POINTS
    print(f"initial_points: {initial_points}")

    # store the guess history
    history = set()

    while True:
        if "_" not in word:
            print('you WIN!!')
            break
        elif initial_points < 1:
            print('you LOSE!!')
            break

    guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
    # decrement initial points
    if guess not in chosen_word \
        and guess not in history \
        and guess not in word:
        initial_points -= 1

    for i, c in enumerate(chosen_word):
        if guess == c:
            word[i] = guess

    # Not decrement twice
    history.add(guess)
    
    # display
    print(f"Points: {initial_points} - {word}")
    print(f"Guessed letters: {history}")


guessing()
```